# Qual a diferença entre cshtml e o html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5, mvc

Existe alguma diferença entre *CSHTML* e *HTML*, principalmente em segurança, desempenho e aplicação? Há alguma perda ao utilizar *HTML* em um projeto *ASP MVC*, e quais são os benefícios de se utilizar o *CSHTML* em um projeto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CSHTML** é um arquivo (extensão .cshtml, de *c-sharp html*) que possui marcações HTML, mas se difere deste por conter códigos usando a sintaxe [Razor](http://www.macoratti.net/11/02/asp_rzr1.htm), que é uma *view engine* de aplicações ASP.NET MVC e WebMatrix, e rodados no servidor usando a linguagem C#. Esta extensão (.cshtml) apenas indica que o arquivo contém a sintaxe Razor na linguagem C# que será interpretada pelo servidor, e como em outras linguagens *server-side*, o retorno é um HTML puro.

Diferenças de *segurança, desempenho e aplicação* entre as duas coisas é algo bastante óbvio, e se fossemos listar todas as diferenças, daria um livro. Uma página HTML, a grosso modo, é apenas uma página com marcações (*tags*) e scripts que só *rodam* no *lado-cliente* (interpretados pelo navegador), podendo ser, da mesma forma, alterada no *lado-cliente*. O CSHTML aceita códigos interpretados pelo servidor (como explicado no início). Com esta noção básica entre as duas coisas, já é possível ter uma noção de aplicação, desempenho e, principalmente, segurança.

Em relação a usar HTML em ASP MVC, não faz muito sentido. Você não precisa de um ambiente avançado (ASP MVC) para criar simples páginas HTML. Mas isso vai depender muito do seu projeto. Se pretende usar CSHTML, supõe-se que tenha um projeto que fará bom uso desse recurso. Geralmente, para se escolher uma linguagem de programação e recursos de servidor, é preciso antes traçar um escopo do projeto que se quer desenvolver. Muitas vezes se escolhe um canhão para matar um coelho. Os benefícios, ao meu ver, são relativos, vai depender do seu projeto aliado aos recursos que você pretende usar nele.

A página [**neste link**](http://www.macoratti.net/11/02/asp_rzr1.htm) é faz um bom apanhado do assunto.